# Entity Framework 7 with Universal Windows Platform Add-Migration

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I'm trying to implement Universal Windows Platform application with EntityFramework and SQLite (according to: http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html) but I have problem with **Add-Migration** command.

Here is my setup:

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 1
- EntityFramework.SQLite: "7.0.0-rc1-final"

Error that I got while adding migrations is:

---

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly that you miss a dll "System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.36.0" in your project.

To solve this problem, you can open the Nuget tool, and search for [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/1.1.36), then in the "Version" label select the Version 1.1.36, by default it is the latest version 1.1.37.

You can also try to update your VS tool, this possible may also solve your problem.